# Flexbox not taking the full height

Tags: css, html, flexbox, materialize

In my webapp's layout, I'm having trouble getting the main content's container (`#loading`) to take the remaining height of the screen. Using flexboxes, I've managed to get `<main>` to grow, but not anything it contains.

JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/1r65v2uj/1/

Answer (score 0):

Was [this](http://jsfiddle.net/1r65v2uj/3/) the effect you were desiring?

I simply added `padding-bottom` and `padding-top` of `50%` each to your `.card-panel`.

```
#loading > .row > .card-panel {
    position: relative;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
    padding-top: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
}
```

**Edit:** You'll need to constrain the parent elements like `main` now, because `.card-panel` will responsively resize to take up whatever size is available to it.

Comment: Not quite, no.  I'm not trying to center the loading circle, I'm trying to make the card-panel take the remainder of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I added `height: 100vh` to the `.card-panel`. See the [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tqvm2bze/).

[image]

Comment: This causes the card-panel to become longer than the screen.  I want it to take whatever portion of the screen is left, not cause an overflow.